# Unusual Results in Modals with Same CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I apologize for the somewhat bad title, but I don't really know how to explain the problem. I'm working on two modals, one to create a task and one to edit a task. However, on the edit task modal, elements underneath bleed through. The strange thing is elements don't bleed through on the create modal, even though they use the exact same css file.

[image: Create Task Modal]
[image: Edit Task Modal]

I am using React with CSS Modules.

I don't have a fiddle currently to reproduce the results as the code is quite tedious to put in, but I will get it up as soon as possible. Is there any reason why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Check the z-index style of the modal and the background components that are coming out on the top. z-index of the model should be more.

Comment: None of them had z-indexes, and the problem wasn't fixed when I added them. It doesn't make sense though for the z-index to matter because both modals use the same css file.